# Unknown issue in solidity random function

Tags: solidity, evm, random

I using this function to generate random numbers (example value of that 3 variables are commented in code below)
this code sometimes works and sometimes does not.
when I tested with manual value and removed random logic after always worked this code so random generation have problems
can you see any mistake?
I using solidity 0.8.11 version

```
function _getSeedValues(uint256 _masterSeed)
        internal
        pure
        returns (
            uint32 dnaSeed,
            uint256 randomSeed,
            uint256 randomValues
        )
    {
        //_masterSeed is block.timestamp

        uint256 mod = 2**10 - 1;
        dnaSeed = uint32(_masterSeed % mod);
        uint256 randMod = 10**10;
        randomSeed =
             uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_masterSeed))) %
             randMod;

        uint256 valueMod = 10**20;
        randomValues =
             uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_masterSeed, DNA_LENGTH))) %
             valueMod;
        //dnaSeed = 1010101010;
        //randomSeed = 8382354398;
        //randomValues = 6277477913484928;
    }
```

Comment: Not directly answering your question, BUT. Relying on a `block.timestamp` to calculate a "random" number is just wrong. block.timestamp is completely predictable and attackers could easily break your smart contract. Please look into this way of generating random numbers: https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf/

Edit: Also this link provides a simple little game of exploiting this vulnerability:https://ethernaut.openzeppelin.com/level/0x4dF32584890A0026e56f7535d0f2C6486753624f

Comment: I tried running your code and it seems to work. What error are you receiving?